# Making the content of a resizable div responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have created a 'virtual desktop' for a web app I'm developing, and into this desktop I can open 'virtual windows'. Each is an absolutely positioned div which can be moved, resized and so on.
I'd like to make the content of (some of) these 'windows' responsive, scaling from 4 columns @ 25% each, down to 1 column @ 100%.

I'm not using any frameworks, as this is a one off edge case that I'm hoping to solve with a custom solution.

I've tried @media, but this has no effect at all as I'm not altering the size of the actual browser window, only the dimensions of the virtual window's content area.

Is there a CSS3 solution that I'm missing here? Essentially I need to alter the width (as a percentage) of a class, based on the dimensions of its parent, where those dimensions are completely independent of the browser window. Essentially, pointing @media to the immediate parent of the class definition I want to alter, rather than the containing viewport.

Is this possible?

Comment: Any reason that you dont use frameworks? jQuery UI is perfect for this kind of stuff. With functions as `draggable()` and `resizable()` it works like a dream.

Comment: I don't use jQuery as it would just be for this specific issue. That's a butt load of code to stretch and shrink a handful of form elements. 

The whole thing is a bit of an apprenticeship piece, so I've hand coded everything from scratch, just for the LOLZ ;)

Comment: Ok! I take it you get paid by the hour ;-). Then its a great reason to not use frameworks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes - it is possible... But:**

You can't do it with a `DIV`.

After a goodly amount of coffee, it dawned on me that `@media` is taking it's dimensions from `document.window`, so the simplest workaround for this is to embed the 'responsive' elements in an `iframe`. This gives`@media` its own, localised document bounds within the main content of the page (or desktop in my case). If my pseudo window content is a separate document, with its own set of bounding dimensions, `@media` works like a dream and I can have responsive layouts inside resizable divs...

Easy when you think about it.

**ASIDE:**

I tried using flexbox, and while this achieved some of what I was after (ie stretching content to fill available space) it failed when it came to shrinking the content down below its `min-width` attribute, and the wrapping mechanism was, to put it bluntly, pretty pants. There are a lot of settings to play with though, and it might well be possible to leverage it for specific use cases. It would definitely be a neater solution.